# Getting a "Can't resolve variable of class" error when trying to access header variable

Tags: c++11

I have a container

```
std::map<std::string, int> map;
```

in an a6.hpp header file but when I try to access map in my source file, I get a "Can't resolve variable or class" error. I have a

```
#include "a6.hpp"
```

line but it's still giving me this error. Could someone help?

Comment: Make sure you included `<map>` and `<string>` before that and better move your variable in cpp file.

Comment: Also make sure that you do not use `using namespace std` or `using std::map`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call your `std::map` variable `map` or any other C++ keyword or else bad things will happen.  Also check your a6.hpp file and make sure it has both includes for map and string.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
```